# Address aggregation contigous blocks, why are some addresses unsumable?

Tags: networking, ip-address

There is a question in one of my past exams that says: "An IP-operator has recieved these IP-addresses:

• 192.168.1.0/26
• 192.168.1.96/27
• 192.168.1.128/27
• 192.168.1.160/27

Q: Sum the networks that can be summed."

So I tried to sum all of the IP-adresses, but it turns out that you can only sum the last two of them, due to adresses ranging from 192.168.1.64-95 do not exist. But why then, can you only sum the last two (192.168.1.128/27, 192.168.1.160/27) and not the three last ones (192.168.1.96/27, 192.168.1.128/27, 192.168.1.160/27) ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem, you need to think of the addresses in binary rather than decimal notation. Bear in mind that the slash-suffix designates the number of *bits* in the network address. To combine, two blocks must match on all but the lowest bit of the network part of the address. This implies that they are numerically adjacent networks, but only 50% of numerically adjacent networks are adjacent because they differ on the lowest bit. The other half of the time, they differ on some other bit as well. That's just the nature of counting in binary.

Thus, for example, you could combine 10.0.2.0/24 and 10.0.3.0/24 into 10.0.2.0/23, because they match on the first 23 bits. You can't do the same for 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24, however, because they only match on the first 22 bits.

If you've got three adjacent networks (with the same netmask length), then the one in the middle can definitely be merged with one of its neighbours, and definitely can't be merged with the other one.